# SAP Fiori Elements - Object Page Table Items XML Annotation

Tags: abap, sap-fiori, sap-gateway

Please, what are the **XML annotations** needed in a Fiori Elements **Object Page** in order to display a table in it?
This app is not a RAP one, this is OData service with gateway (SEGW).

Example: Main Entity Purchase Orders and in Object Page display all PO Items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add ReferenceFacet annotations that point to the LineItem annotation.

ReferenceFacet annotations will create a new section in the Object Page. The LineItem annotation will add a table to it.

More details you can find in the [documentation](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/17564c2b77234ce69a88511b03d369f9).

Facet annotation:

```xml
<Annotation Term="UI.Facets">
    <Record Type="UI.ReferenceFacet">
        <PropertyValue Property="ID" String="to_Children"/>
        <PropertyValue Property="Target" AnnotationPath="children/@UI.LineItem"/>
        <PropertyValue Property="Label" String="{@i18n>CHILDREN_LABEL}"/>
    </Record>
</Annotation>
```

LineItem annotation

```xml
<Annotations Target="MyService.Children" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm">
    <Annotation Term="UI.LineItem">
        <Collection>
            <Record Type="UI.DataField">
                <PropertyValue Property="Value" Path="FullName"/>
            </Record>
            <Record Type="UI.DataField">
                <PropertyValue Property="Value" Path="Age"/>
            </Record>
            <Record Type="UI.DataField">
                <PropertyValue Property="Value" Path="EyeColor"/>
            </Record>
        </Collection>
    </Annotation>
</Annotations>
```